# Using ARM templates to create multiple federated credentials for UMIs

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a list of UMIs that I am creating with the `Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities` ARM template resource. Let's say I have ten of these in my list.

For each UMI, I want to create federated credentials to allow tokens from several OIDC providers.

I planned to use [resource iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources), but it doesn't appear I can nest the [fed creds child resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.managedidentity/userassignedidentities/federatedidentitycredentials?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) when using an iterator.

So my question is: How do I either **a)** create federated credentials that allow tokens from multiple OIDC providers or **b)** write an ARM template that can do a nested for loop? i.e. "for each UMI create ***x*** fed creds"

**Here's the template I started with**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "managedIdNames": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
      "copy": {
        "name": "managedIdentityIterator",
        "count": "[length(parameters('managedIdNames'))]"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2023-01-31",
      "name": "[parameters('managedIdNames')[copyIndex()].name]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials",
          "copy": {
            "name": "fedCredsIterator",
            "count": "[length(parameters('oidcProviders'))]"
          },
          "apiVersion": "2023-01-31",
          "name": "string",
          "properties": {
            "audiences": [ "api://AzureADTokenExchange" ],
            "issuer": "[parameters('oidcProviders')[copyIndex()].url]",
            "subject": "system:serviceaccount:[parameters('k8sNamespace')]:[parameters('managedIdNames')[copyIndex()].name]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here's the error that gave me**

```
Code: InvalidSchema
Message: The template is invalid. Error: 'The template resource 'string' at line '22' column '19' is not valid. Copying nested resources is not supported. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-multiple-instances for usage details.'
2023-10-23 14:10:02,593 - MainProcess - ERROR - (azurehelper:upload_all_templates_ts:1677) - Template upload failed - Exception raised in a thread
```

**Here's the template I am stuck with now**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "managedIdNames": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
      "name": "[parameters('managedIdNames')[copyIndex()].name]",
      "apiVersion": "2023-01-31",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "managedIdentityIterator",
        "count": "[length(parameters('managedIdNames'))]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials",
      "name": "[format('???/fedCreds{0}', copyIndex())]",
      "apiVersion": "2023-01-31",
      "properties": {
        "audiences": [
          "api://AzureADTokenExchange"
        ],
        "issuer": "[parameters('oidcProviders')[copyIndex()].url]",
        "subject": "system:serviceaccount:[parameters('k8sNamespace')]:[parameters('managedIdNames')[???].name]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "???"
      ],
      "copy": {
        "name": "fedCredsIterator",
        "count": "[length(parameters('oidcProviders'))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It looks like I will have to create something flat to iterate over. I am doing that now. But I am still open to suggestions if someone knows how I could make the above work.

Comment: Iterating over a flat map doesn't help because I now get errors like "The resource Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/xyz is defined multiple times in a template". I am now thinking I need to break this into a two-step process: Create the UMIs. Then create the fed creds.

Comment: I may be getting closer to a solution with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/azure-resource-manager/advanced-templates/objects-as-parameters... but I am fighting off little bugs here and there. I will update once I figure this out.

Comment: It seems like you cannot nest the fed creds child resource when using an iterator. Is PowerShell works in your case? @matthiasdenu

Comment: @Jahnavi Correct. Nesting child resources when using an iterator is not allowed (I found out the hard way). I've accepted your answer below. Also, fwiw, I had to completely refactor our code so that Python handles the iteration (instead of the ARM template) and builds the `dependsOn` list for each fed creds resource, so that no concurrency error is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `dependsOn` property, you can provision many new federated identity credentials consecutively.

I tried below code to create three new federated identity credentials progressively on a user-assigned managed identity.

```bash
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "userAssignedIdentities_parent": {
      "defaultValue": "parent_uami",
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-31-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('userAssignedIdentities_parent')]",
      "location": "eastus"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials",
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-31-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('userAssignedIdentities_parent'), '/fic01')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('userAssignedIdentities_parent'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "issuer": "https://kubernetes-oauth.azure.com",
        "subject": "fic01",
        "audiences": [
          "api://AzureADTokenExchange"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials",
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-31-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('userAssignedIdentities_parent'), '/fic02')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('userAssignedIdentities_parent'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials', parameters('userAssignedIdentities_parent'), 'fic01')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "issuer": "https://kubernetes-oauth.azure.com",
        "subject": "fic02",
        "audiences": [
          "api://AzureADTokenExchange"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials",
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-31-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('userAssignedIdentities_parent'), '/fic03')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('userAssignedIdentities_parent'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials', parameters('userAssignedIdentities_parent'), 'fic02')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "issuer": "https://kubernetes-oauth.azure.com",
        "subject": "fic03",
        "audiences": [
          "api://AzureADTokenExchange"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes. This is exactly the approach I had to take. I've accepted your answer so that anyone in the future with the same issue knows this is how I solved it. Thank you.