# Can UMI federated credentials allow tokens from multiple issuers?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to create a single [federatedIdentityCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.managedidentity/2023-01-31/userassignedidentities/federatedidentitycredentials?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) resource that allows tokens from multiple OIDC providers?

I am asking about *Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials*.

I see that the 'issuer' property is a string. This leads me to assume that there may only be one issuer per fed creds. Is that assumption correct?

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials",
  "apiVersion": "2023-01-31",
  "name": "string",
  "properties": {
    "audiences": [ "string" ],
    "issuer": "string",
    "subject": "string"
  }
}
```

This relates to my use case here: [Using ARM templates to create multiple federated credentials for UMIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77347839/using-arm-templates-to-create-multiple-federated-credentials-for-umis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can UMI federated credentials allow tokens from multiple issuers?

Firstly, to achieve your requirement, you need to look into the way that each `federatedIdentityCredentials` resource is meant to be linked to a specific issuer.

Create more than one of `federatedIdentityCredentials` resources, one for each to accept tokens from different issuers.

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77388324/19785512) worked by me on the same issue with detailed code.

*Sample code format looks like below:*

```bash
"resources":[
{
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials",
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-31-preview",
      "name": "xxxx",
      "properties": {
        "issuer": "1xxx",
        "subject": "xxx",
        "audiences": [ ]
      }
    },
 {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/federatedIdentityCredentials",
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-31-preview",
      "name": "xxxx",
      "properties": {
        "issuer": "2xxx",
        "subject": "xxx",
        "audiences": [ ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for the late reply. Yes, this is what I had to do. And "No." would be the answer to my question—UMI federated credentials _do not_ allow tokens from multiple issuers. You must have one federatedIdentityCredentials per issuer. So I had to refactor some code.